# Splice inside light pole

Tags: electrical, lighting

I am replacing a rotted out light pole in my yard.  The underground feeder that runs to the light pole is only long enough to run halfway up the new light pole.  Is it acceptable to splice an extra length of cable to run to the top of the light pole?  I don't know if this is acceptable since there will be a splice hidden inside the light pole.

Comment: Uh, what is your concern? That the light pole might burn down? Is it made of wood?

Comment: Metal pole.  I just want to be sure I'm not overlooking anything. Im just not certain if a hidden junction in the pole is an issue.

Comment: Not really. Ideally, the connection should be made in an accessible place but if it doesn't reach, it doesn't reach.

Comment: Maybe somebody that knows more than me could comment on whether "Tyco Electronics,  Model # CPGI-1116377-2, Home Depot SKU # 302061 
Romex Splice Kit 2 Wire" is acceptable in an outdoor setting.

Comment: Those splice kits are by far more of a pain and probably not as reliable as good old fashion wire nuts.

Comment: +1 for just using wire nuts, and at Home Depot they also have blue ones with goo inside that are made for wet locations.

Comment: @TylerDurden The biggest concern is not fire but shock hazard.  If the pole is grounded correctly a hot to ground will trip the breaker but a neutral to ground will not.  If you extend, to protect yourself and others, put that circuit on a GFCI to prevent the neutral to ground shocks.

Comment: @diceless If the pole is in the ground, it is grounded.

Comment: @TylerDurden A neutral to ground short is deceptively dangerous.  Under normal conditions, no one will notice.  But if someone touches the pole when they are a better ground conductor (ie, standing in a pool of water), they will be shocked.  Trust me, some nimrod used the ground conductor as the neutral in my house and I got a good shock when I touched the metal box.  Found this about a year after buying the house and it was just waiting for me to touch the box while barefoot.

Answer (score 3):

No -- splices need to be accessible in case something gets messed up and the splice needs re-doing.  There *should* be a space in the base of the lamppost to make the needed splice/connection, though -- look for an access panel as part of the base.

Answer (score 0):

Code says that splices have to be accessible, although I can think of two exceptions:  My well has a splice between the direct burial line running across my yard to the 3 strands of wire that go down the bore.  This splice is just in the riser pipe that brings power from the burial trench to the well cap.  There is another splice at the pump.  Those are covered with plastic waterproof compression seals.

Normally I would expect the base to have a built in junction box for splicing.  After all, you may have  multiple lights on that circuit.  If it's a home made light this may not be the case.

Another possibility is that it's low voltage lighting.  Code is a lot more liberal for that, since the risk of electrocution is much lower.

If you choose to ignore code, and splice anyway, I would suggest using crimp connectors and heat shrink tubing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can just splice it, but if possible don't just twist it and tape it - that's probably asking for a short sometime in the future, it would be best to splice and solder it and tape it.

http://nicab.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Wire-splice-solderikng.jpg

Comment: I strongly suspect this would be a violation of the National Electrical Code (in the US). Splices are to be accessible, and not hidden.